# WordPress: How do I change the Header color on a specific page

Tags: php, css, wordpress

Is there a way to change the header color of a WordPress site for a specific page without affecting the other pages?

For example, if I have a site with the following pages:

- Home
- Projects
- Blog
- Contact me

And then I've set the header with, say, `background-color: grey`.

But then for the `blog` page **only**, I want to set the header to have `background-color: yellow`.

**How can go about this situation?**

In my case, here is the page: http://xusom2.mymediapaldesign.com/?page_id=320

(Kindly note this link doesn't work; it's used only for illustration.)

Comment: You have the class `page-id-320` on the body so you can simply target with that class.

Comment: check my answer with screenshot

Answer (score 2):

WordPress has a function [`body_class()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class). You can use `page-id-{ID}` css class to target specific page given by page id. In your case `.page-id-320`.

Answer (score 0):

**If you're OK with modifying your PHP:**

- Go to your relevant .php document (pages, or post) and look for the code that calls the header.
- Then substitute it with something like this:

---

```
if ( is_page($PAGE_ID_WHERE_YOU_WANT_A_DIFFERENT_HEADER) ) :
    get_header(modified);
else :
    get_header();
endif;
?>
```

---

- Make a new `header.php` file with your custom colours and/or style and save it as `header-modified.php`.

Now your WordPress installation will load your modified header for the page with ID `$PAGE_ID_WHERE_YOU_WANT_A_DIFFERENT_HEADER`

Hope I helped.

Answer (score 0):

Themes have a template tag for the body tag which will help theme authors to style more effectively with CSS. The Template Tag is called body_class. This function gives the body element different classes and can be added, typically, in the header.php's HTML body tag. You can use this code.

```
<body <?php if ($_GET['page_id']=='320') { body_class( 'class-name' ); } ?>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress generated unique class for each page. you already have class `page-id-320`.

Add the below style in your css `wp-content/themes/xusom/css/wpex-responsive.css` file.

```
body.page-id-320 #top-bar-wrap {
 background: red;
}
```

[image]

Refer this URL:
Article: http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-style-each-wordpress-post-differently/
Plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/page-specific-menu-items/

Answer (score 0):

The body of http://xusom2.mymediapaldesign.com/?page_id=320
has class page-id-320.
You can use this class to custom color for only header.

You can add this to style.css or a custom css box on admin (if your theme supports custom css):

```
.page-id-320 #site-header, .page-id-320 #site-navigation li{
    background-color: #f60!important;
}
```

Here is the example to change header to orange instead of blue.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it with pure css.
Its much better in css since its a pure UI issue and not logic.

Add this to he body and then apply the css

#### HTML

```
<body class="myPage"...>
 
  <header>....
```

#### CSS

```
.myPage .header{
  // specific style
}
```

Comment: you do realize that the OP's site is WordPress and already has a unique class in body tag in each page... you don't need to add a class.

Comment: I know it, but what if he copy the content to another page/template, In his page its `page-320` but you want something generic

Comment: that maybe then another story but still there's a class for templates.. like what he has right now is using the default `page-template-default`. and because this is template, do you think `<body class="myPage"...>` will just add that on that specific page?